# german gunning fog index function

Tags: text-mining

I would like to analyse some text and most of my Reviews are german. Does anyone know if python has a good gunning fog index function for german language? I couldnt find anything

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be rather in the field of linguistics than related to data science, but nevertheless:

To my knowledge, the "gunning fog index" as measure for understandability is intended for english language only, per definition.

For some tools intended for german, see 
https://klartext.uni-hohenheim.de/hix (page in german), which refers to a german SMOG index. There are implementations of SMOG listed in PyPI, but you may need to find the appropriate values to configure them for german language.